# Javascript does not work with every iteration of PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Javascript that is supposed to trigger on every php foreach loop iteration, but instead it only works on the first iteration of another loop that shows html table with inputs. For now, the Javascript is only in the **head** of an html like this: `<script src='script.js' defer></script>`.

I tried putting in the script inside the foreach loop, outside, directly without refrence link. Adding to foreach `$i` and inside id like `id='identification_".$i."'`.

Here's the php file:

```
foreach ($output as $row) {
    if ($row["team_name"] != $current_team) {
        // Output the team name if it's different from the previous row
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='team-members'>

                <a>" . ($row["team_mem"] ? $row["team_mem"] : "-") . "</a>
                <input type='hidden' value=" . $row["team_nr"] . " name='team_nr'>
                <input type='hidden' value='" . $rowspan . "' name='team_size'>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type='number' class='kills'>
            </td>


            <td rowspan='$rowspan'>
                <input type='number' oninput='calculateMultiplier(this.value)' id='multiplier_input'>
            </td>
            <td rowspan='$rowspan'>
                <a id='total_kills' data-default-value='0'></a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan='$rowspan'>
                <a id='multiplier' data-default-value='1.00'></a>
            </td>
           <td rowspan='$rowspan'>
                <a id='total_round' data-default-value='0'></a>
            </td>
            <td rowspan='$rowspan'>
                E
            </td>
            

        </tr>";
        $current_team = $row["team_name"];
    } else {
        // Output an empty cell for the team number and name if it's the same as the previous row
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='team-members'>
               <a>" . ($row["team_mem"] ? $row["team_mem"] : "-") . "</a>
            </td>

             <td>
                <input type='number' class='kills'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        

    ";
    }
}
```

and javascript:

```
// pobieramy element, który wyświetla sumę punktów
const total_kills = document.getElementById('total_kills');

// ustawiamy początkową wartość na wartość z atrybutu "data-default-value"
total_kills.textContent = total_kills.getAttribute('data-default-value');

// pobieramy element, który wyświetla wartość mnożnika
const multiplier_box = document.getElementById('multiplier');
multiplier_box.setAttribute('data-default-value', '1.00');
multiplier_box.textContent = multiplier_box.getAttribute('data-default-value');

// pobieramy element, który wyświetla wynik mnożenia
const total_round = document.getElementById('total_round');
total_round.setAttribute('data-default-value', '0');
total_round.textContent = total_round.getAttribute('data-default-value');

// dodajemy obsługę zdarzenia oninput do każdego pola input
const kills = document.querySelectorAll('.kills');  
kills.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', sum);
});

// funkcja, która oblicza sumę punktów i aktualizuje wyświetlaną wartość
function sum() {
  let all_kills = 0;
  kills.forEach((input) => {
    // jeśli pole input ma wartość, dodajemy ją do sumy
    if (input.value) {
      all_kills += parseInt(input.value);
    }
  });
  // aktualizujemy wyświetlaną wartość sumy
  total_kills.textContent = all_kills;

  // obliczamy wynik mnożenia
  const multiplier = parseFloat(multiplier_box.textContent);
  const total_round_box = all_kills * multiplier;
  // aktualizujemy wyświetlaną wartość wyniku
  total_round.textContent = total_round_box;
}

// dodajemy obsługę zdarzenia oninput do elementu multip

multiplier_box.addEventListener('input', sum);

// wywołujemy funkcję sum() na początku, aby obliczyć początkową wartość wyniku
sum();
```

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser after your PHP code has completely finished, it doesn't execute in the PHP loop iterations.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't use the same IDs in every row of the table. Use classes, and then use event delegation in the JavaScript.

Comment: Since IDs are unique, `document.getElementById()` always returns the first match. So you can't use that to process multiple table rows.

Comment: Thank you, so what would be a good idea to implement this ? I have a page with a list of items and when user selects one of the items I need the javascript to trigger.

Comment: As Barmar said, use a class, consider using event delegation and/or document.querySelectorAll() to select all the elements and bind a click event to them

Comment: So is it enough to have <script> inside head, and only head? Without putting it in inside foreach?

Comment: Yes that would be a lot more normal